# How can I convert an object string to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, type-conversion

How can I convert the string to an Object?

```js
var string = "{ test: 'hello' }";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward, please search google before posting.

```
const obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work as the O.P.'s example is not JSON. You could parse it as JSON5 though: https://json5.org/ — just need to `const JSON5 = npm require('json5')` and then `const obj = JSON5.parse("{ test: 'hello' }")`.

Comment: Yeah json5 will work thanks @NicholasCarey 
I forgot that json5 existed

Comment: OP marked JSON as one of the tags, but I guess you're right for the lack of quotes between the key. Still, not a very well formed question